# Explicit expression for 1-forms which produce, by exterior derivative, a given 2-form in DR-cohomology for twice punctured plane

Tags: algebraic-topology

I want to check a possible solution to a problem I cannot solve:

We know that closed 2-forms for $R^2-\{p,q\}$ are exact. Given a closed 2-form, what is a 1-form that gives us that 2-form under exterior derivative?

For $R^2-\{p\}$, just one point removed, we can do so in polar coordinates:

ω=f(r,θ)dr∧dθ. Then $h=(\int_1^r f(u,θ)du)dθ$ is a primitive of ω.

for $R^2-\{p,q\}$, could I consider two tangent circles of equal radius centered at each point and integrate points inside each circle just like the above, and on the outside sum the integrals?

Can anyone give the computation?

(this is not an assigned HW problem, just self reading a book)

Anyone ?

Comment: This sounds like an exercise from Bott&Tu.  Try writing $\omega=\omega_1+\omega_2$, where $\omega_1$ is defined on $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{p\}$ and $\omega_2$ is defined on $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{q\}$. This you can do with a partition of unity subordinate to an appropriate cover of $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{p,q\}$. I think Bott&Tu explain it when they introduce the  Mayer-Vietoris argument.

Comment: Look up the Poincare Lemma in whatever textbook you're reading.

Comment: @Ryan Budney  I looked up and does not seem to help this one.

Comment: @Gil Bor  yes it is, the issue is not to prove H^2 is trivial, I want the one form explicitly calculated. Do you know what it is?

Comment: Find an explicit partition of unity, then you will get $\omega_1, \omega_2$ explicitly, then apply yr formula to each of them. Note that "the" 1-form you are looking for is not unique, you can add to it any exact 1-form $df$.

Comment: @Gil Bor.  d(roh w_1+ roh w_2). Introduces extra terms because now the partition of

Comment: @Gil Bor   I think I got it:

Comment: @Gil Bor   I think I got it:   d w_1= \roh_u f and d w_2=\roh_v f then d(w_1+w+2)= (\roh_u + \roh_v) f= f     each operating on their own side and not worrying about the other hole since the \roh's suppress the function there right :)

Comment: That's right. Congratulations.

Comment: @Gil Bor thanks!!!! :))))))))))